# SQLite diagram ERD for unknown number of tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, erd

I have a GPS android app that I have made. It uses a SQLite database on the SD card for storing the location data. I am trying make up an ERD (Entity–relationship diagrams) for the database. This is where I am having problems. The database has one master table for the tracks and one for the waypoint groups (a collection of one or more waypoints). These tables do not have the location data in them but just the name of the track or waypoint group, start/stop time and date, and a uid. For each row in these tables a new table is made that contains the latitude and longitude info. In the sub table each row is one point or vertex. And the sub table name is the uid of the "master" table plus "t_" or "w_" for traks or waypoints. This is what I came up with using https://www.draw.io:

http://s10.postimg.org/usqsrwjmx/Untitled_Diagram.png

(sorry I do not have the 10 rep points to post an image, lol)

I think that composition link between the tables is right as the sub table only exists if there is a row in the master table. If the master row is deleted the corresponding sub table is also deleted. But how to show that there is a sub table for every row in the master table? It is also a little weird because there is no need for a FK in the sub table as the table name provides this function.

I don't think that I want to change my database structure at this late date as the app is to be sent out for testing shortly, but I would be interested in other (superior) database designs for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a relational database data is linked. In your database, however, not only data is linked but also data with table names. Thus you are mixing content with structure.

As far as I know you cannot display this in an ERD. You cannot implement this correctly in your dbms either (such that your dbms knows about the structure and helps you with appropriate constraints).

You are not using your RDBMS properly. So in spite of the late date: if I were in your place, I would change this into a proper relational database model.

EDIT: A proper relational model would simply be to have only *one* track_detail table with the track id in a column rather than in its name. Same for waypoint_detail with the master's waypoint id. No big change actually.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Thorsten. OK, just to make sure I got your point. I should have one table with all of the track vertices (for all tracks) then the FK would be the uid of the "master" track. Yes, I can see that. Any performance issues with having one massive table, potentially with a few hundred thousand records, rather then many tables with a few thousand records each?

Comment: Also, I am not sure I see the down side to how I have it now. I guess the risk would be if the app needed, in the future, to pass data outside of its self to a "real" RDBMS system. Which is a real risk as they do have an oracle database and an esri SDE as well....

Comment: I don't consider a few hundred thousand records that big. And this is what a dbms is all about: find the appropriate records as fast as possible. With FK constraints and indexes applied, the dbms can easily find the best method to get to the data. That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: As to downsides: Think about how you would select the track with the most associated points for example. Or the tracks that are closest to your current position. This is rather easy with a relational database as I describe, but even impossible with SQL alone in your model.

Comment: OK, thanks for sorting me out. I am going to look at changing it as you suggested.